# Enumerable.Range implementation

Tags: .net, ienumerable, implementation, range

What is the *precise* implementation of Enumerable.Range in .Net; preferable .Net 4? Is it a yielded for-loop? A custom implementation (IEnumerable, IEnumerator) or?

Comment: decompile it with reflector http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Comment: The reason I care about this is because I want to know how efficient the implementation is and how I'd go about creating my own implementation for e.g. Int64 and what have you.

Comment: It looks like it's the C# compiler than converts this into classes. The CLR has no notion of yield return. I'm also interested in possible compiler optimizations (CLR JIT or C# compiler) on IEnumerables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408452/why-enumerable-range-is-faster-than-a-direct-yield-loop/408494#408494) on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408452/why-enumerable-range-is-faster-than-a-direct-yield-loop) should give you the answer:

```
public static class Enumerable {
    public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int start, int count) {
        var end = start + count;
        for(var current = start; current < end; ++current) {
            yield return current;
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't the *exact* code, as there is a lot of error checking etc. going on within the `Range` method, and internally, it calls other methods, however, the quoted code above is the "essence" of the `Range` routine.

Examining the code in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) should provide you with far more information.

Comment: I didn't want the essence, I wanted the precise answer - but I appreciate that this is not possible due to license restrictions. Thanks for the input, I've now used reflector and found the answer.

Comment: It's more like: `if (!valid) throw exception; else return RangeInternal(...);` in which `RangeInternal` is an iterator. This is an important distinction, since if you call `Range` with invalid arguments, you'll get the exception immediately. If the `Range` method used `yield` directly, you didn't get an exception until you `foreach`ed the collection.

Comment: @Mehrdad - That's a very good point that the exception is (potentially) thrown immediately rather than deferred, like the iteration itself.  It's what I was alluding to when I mentioned about error checking, but you have described it more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it a yielded for-loop? A custom implementation (IEnumerable, IEnumerator)?

Both :-)

---

**.NET 4**

In February 2014, [Microsoft put a .NET Source Code browser online](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingTheNewRoslynpoweredNETFrameworkReferenceSource.aspx). Thus, your question can now be answered with an offical source:

`Enumerable.Range` performs error checking and then calls the private method `RangeIterator`, which uses a **a yielded for-loop**.

The [license](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/license.html) still does not allow posting the code here, but you can look at it yourself at this link:

- https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,fda9d378095a6464

---

**.NET Core**

.NET Core is licensed under the more permissive MIT license. I am not a lawyer, so I don't know if this means I may copy-and-paste it to StackOverflow or not, but here is the direct link to their `Enumerable.Range` implementation, which uses **a custom RangeIterator object**:

- https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/143df51926f2ad397fef9c9ca7ede88e2721e801/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Range.cs

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to see the implementation for yourself. It checks arguments and throws exception at the time of calling, so the `Range` method itself is not an iterator method. It calls another method which is an iterator method. It's not OK to post the exact code due to [license restrictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20153/posting-code-from-reflector/20155#20155).

Answer (score 1):

A slight but significant difference in the Reflector output (as well as the argument check and extra level of internalisation mentioned in CraigTP's answer and its comments):

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int start, int count) {
    for(int current = 0; current < count; ++current) {
        yield return start + current;
    }
}
```

That is, instead of another local variable, they apply an extra addition for every yield.